# Thinking about $ax + by = ab$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is embarrassing because I know this is fairly simple, but I'm hitting a mental block and not having much luck with any references I'm aware of.

What properties does $ax + by = ab$ have? (a and b are integers)

I guess I'm sort of thinking...

1. Is there always a solution? (I think so)
2. How many solutions are there?
3. Is there always a solution where neither x or y is zero? (not sure)

Does this sort of equation look familiar to anyone else? Does it remind you of anything? I feel like it must have some obvious properties.

Comment: If you are working in the integers, you could make a and b a linear combination that equals 1 with the euclidean algorithm, so there is always a solution in the integers by scaling everything afterwards. This is also a solution with x,y not equal to 0 (neither x nor y is zero)

Comment: @theREALyumdub not $1$, but the gcd.

Comment: I knew there must have been something to do with gcds and the euclidean algorithm, thanks :D

Comment: Of course there is a solution, $x=b, y=0$. And there are infinitely many.  No gcd stuff needed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas True. Molehills with sledgehammers I guess

Comment: Do $\,x,y\,$ denote integers?  If so, it's elementary number theory, not linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

$1.$ There is always a solution: we can write the greatest common denominator as $ax+by$, hence we just need to scale that solution in order to get a solution for $ab$. (If $a, b$ are zero it is trivial to see there is a solution)

$2.$ The number of solutions is infinite. Let $ax+by = \gcd(a, b)$. One of $a$ or $b$ must be non-zero. WLOG let $a$ be non-zero, then we can keep increasing $y$ by one and subtracting by $\frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}(ax+by)$ to get another solution. (Again, the case where either $a, b$ are zero is trivial)

$3.$ The only time where we do not find a solution where both $x, y$ are zero is when only one of $a, b$ are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $b\neq 0$, this is the straight line $y=-\frac{a}{b}x+a$. There are infinitely many $(x,y)$ pairs. If $b=0, a\neq 0$ then $x=0$, so $(0,y)$ where $y$ being any number is a solution. So again infinitely many solutions. So your 3rd statement is wrong.